# I am getting this type of error while creating apk file expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I used `expo build:android` for creating app

```
   Error: Can't find react-native in package.json dependencies
    Error: react-native is not installed. Please run `npm install` or `yarn` in your project directory.
    There is an error with your project. See above logs for information.
    Error: There is an error with your project. See above logs for information.
        at C:\Users\softb\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\exp.ts:665:15
        at Command.<anonymous> (C:\Users\softb\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\exp.ts:346:7)
```

Btw I installed `npm install react-native` from my default cmd.but when tries to install from project directory I get this error.

```
I:\Codecanyon\singal res\code>npm install react-native
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: react@16.13.1
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"16.13.1" from react-native@0.63.4
npm WARN   node_modules/react-native
npm WARN     react-native@"*" from the root project
npm WARN     1 more (@unimodules/react-native-adapter)
npm WARN   1 more (react-native-web)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"17.0.1" from react-dom@17.0.1
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   peer react-dom@">=16.5.1" from react-native-web@0.13.18
npm WARN   node_modules/react-native-web
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@bit%2fstryber.matterhorn.loading-skeleton - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@bit/stryber.matterhorn.loading-skeleton@^0.0.1' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\softb\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-05T08_10_48_624Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Checkout the StackOverflow answer, may help you... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43919115/npm-cant-find-dependencies-for-some-react-native-modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting `node_modules` folder and then reinstall the dependencies with `npm install`

Also make sure to run `expo build:android` command inside your project's root directory.